# Testng: Is it possible to skip the method by checking the parameters

Tags: parameters, testng

Method1 has one parameter named as "Param1", if Param1 value is equal to 'True', it means execute the below method. Otherwise, skip this method and execute next method 'Method2'.

```
@Parameters({"Param1"})
    public void Method1(String Param1) 
    {
        //Perform Some operations
    }

//Method2 has one parameter named as "Param2"               
@Parameters({"Param2"})
    public void Method2(String Param1) 
    {
        //Perform Some operations
    }
```

For Example: If Param1 value will be `true`, it means that method `Method1`  will be executed. Otherwise, it will skip method `Method1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code sample:**

```
 @Test
 @Parameters("testStatus")
  public void testMethod1(boolean testStatus) {
     System.out.println("TestStatus: "+testStatus);
     System.out.println();
     if(testStatus == true){
         throw new SkipException("This test is being skipped...");
     }
      System.out.println("test 333333");
  }

 @Test
  public void testMethod2() {
      System.out.println("test 2222");
  }
```

**TestNG XML:**

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

<test name="Test1">
  <parameter name="testStatus" value="true"/> 
  <classes>
    <class name="packagename.ClassName"/>
  </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

In the above code, if parameter is true then the testMethod1 will be skipped and otherwise it will run as it is. I hope this will fill your requirement.